# How to know the Share button is clicked in RPPreviewViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, replaykit

I have to share the video on the basis of condition in ReplayKit. How can I know the Sharing button is pressed.

Comment: What have you tried? Who creates the share button?

Comment: it is the default button at bottom left that appears on previewViewController. Now I got it. When we share video, didFinishWithActivityTypes is called with UIActivityType. There we can do the necessary coding.